# how to load a selected amount of items in MVVM in a listbox windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, observablecollection

I make a call to get more than 1000 items back, then I bind this to the listbox on windows phone, is there maybe a property or something I can set on the listbox in xaml to display only a certain amount of items, or something else I can do, I am not sure how to handle this

Answer (score 3):

You could use a LINQ statement to limit the number of items in your list... MyBindedProperty is the property which is databound to your listbox.

```cs
    List<string> listOfItems = GetMyBunchOfItemsFromSomewhere();
    numberOfRecords = 10;
    MyBindedProperty = listOfItems.Take(numberOfRecords);
```

Comment: cool thanx for the help, based on that code how can I then add the next 10 records to the bindedProperty, on for example the listbox lastitem reached event

Comment: If what you mean is that you want the last 10 records from your collection than you can expand your linq query to e.g.

MyBindedProperty = listOfItems.OrderByDescending(c => c).Take(numberOfRecords);

Comment: no sorry let me clarify, I am making a list of over 1000 items, to which I want to bind the listbox control. the problem is windows phone runs out of memory. so what I want to do is load for example 10 items from that list and display it on the listbox, then once that 10 items is viewed (??) the following 10 items populates in the listbox

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for some kind of paging control. If you are able to make it event triggered to view the next 10 items, then you could create two lists: one for the complete list, one for the items to be shown. After viewing the first 10, trigger an event to remove those ten from the complete collection and take the next 10 into your binded property which will trigger the UI to be updated...

Answer (score 0):

VERY helpful tutorial! to detect when the listbox has reached its limit

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/04/06/wp7-how-to-extend-listbox-when-reaching-last-item.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage